# How can i multiply all columns next to each other in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A     B    C     D    E    F
0     1    2     3    1    4
2     1    4     3    2    4
3     1    2     1    1    2
```

I try to multiple the first and second, third and fourth and fifth and sixth columns, but can't find the solution for this. I try to get a dataframe like this:

```
A    C    E
0    6    4
2    12   8
3    2    2
```

Answer (score 5):

A common trick in `pandas` is grouping by every `n` values using floor division.  Do this along `axis=1` to get your desired output.

---

```
n = 2

df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // n, axis=1).prod()
```

```
   0   1  2
0  0   6  4
1  2  12  8
2  3   2  2
```

Answer (score 5):

Slice with strides of two and multiply. This solution is optimised for N=2 (and also assumes there are an even number of columns).

```
df.iloc[:, ::2] * df.iloc[:, 1::2].values

   A   C  E
0  0   6  4
1  2  12  8
2  3   2  2
```

Answer (score 4):

What I will do `shift` with `reindex`

```
df.shift(-1,axis=1).mul(df).reindex(columns=df.columns[::2])
Out[12]: 
     A     C    E
0  0.0   6.0  4.0
1  2.0  12.0  8.0
2  3.0   2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pd.concate([df.iloc[:,i]*df.iloc[:,i+1] for i in range(0,len(df.columns),2)],
           axis=1)
```